# How to call a C++ delegated function from C#, when C++ call C# functions?

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop

I would like to call a C# library from C++.

The C# library, request a delegated function, 
in order to report the results.

Maybe my purpose is confusing: the conception is, C++ call C# function, and the C# function would call a callback function from C++.

I have been blocked in the C# call C++ callback function , the COM Interop is arcane for me.

My example code be :

C# code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpLibraryNameSpace
{
    // Interface declaration.
    public delegate int NativeDelegateType(int x);
    //public delegate int NativeDelegateType([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string arg1);

    public interface ManagedInterface
    {
        int Add(int Number1, int Number2);

        int CalltheCallbackFun(NativeDelegateType callbackFun);
    };


    // Interface implementation.
    public class ManagedCSharpClass : ManagedInterface
    {
        public int Add(int Number1, int Number2)
        {
            Console.Write("Add\n");
            return Number1 + Number2;
        }

        public int 
            CalltheCallbackFun(
            /*[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]*/ NativeDelegateType callbackFun)
        {
            Console.Write("BB\n");
            string str;
            str = "AAA";
           unsafe
           {
               fixed (char* p = str)
               {
                   Console.Write("before call callbackFun\n");

                   callbackFun(0x01);
               }
           }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The C++ code :

```
#include <windows.h>
// Import the type library.

#import "CSharpLibrary.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace CSharpLibrary;

 typedef void (__stdcall * C_Callback)(int);

 __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall theCallback(void)
{
    return 0;
}/*theCallback*/

 class CPPcallback :public _NativeDelegateType
 {
 public:
     CPPcallback(){};
            virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount( 
            /* [out] */ UINT *pctinfo)
        {
            return E_NOTIMPL;
        }

        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfo( 
            /* [in] */ UINT iTInfo,
            /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
            /* [out] */ ITypeInfo **ppTInfo)
        {

             if (ppTInfo == NULL)
                return E_INVALIDARG;
            *ppTInfo = NULL;

            if(iTInfo != 0)
                return DISP_E_BADINDEX;

            AddRef();      // AddRef and return pointer to cached
                               // typeinfo for this object.
            *ppTInfo = NULL;

            return NOERROR;
        }

        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNames( 
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [size_is][in] */ LPOLESTR *rgszNames,
        /* [in] */ UINT cNames,
        /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
        /* [size_is][out] */ DISPID *rgDispId)
        {
            return E_NOTIMPL;
        }

        virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke( 
        /* [in] */ DISPID dispIdMember,
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
        /* [in] */ WORD wFlags,
        /* [out][in] */ DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,
        /* [out] */ VARIANT *pVarResult,
        /* [out] */ EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo,
        /* [out] */ UINT *puArgErr)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(/* [in] */ REFIID riid,
                /* [iid_is][out] */ void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject)
        {
            if (riid == IID_IUnknown) 
            {
                *ppvObject = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this); 
                AddRef();
                return S_OK;
            }

            if (riid == IID_IDispatch) {
                *ppvObject = static_cast<IDispatch*>(this); 
                AddRef();
                return S_OK;
            }

            //if (riid == IID_CPPcallback ) 
            {
                *ppvObject = static_cast<CPPcallback*>(this);
                AddRef();
                return S_OK;
            }

            *ppvObject = NULL;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }

        virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef( void)
        {
            return InterlockedIncrement(&_refCount);
        }

        virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release( void)
        {
            return  InterlockedDecrement(&_refCount);
        }

 private:
        long _refCount;
 };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    ManagedInterfacePtr CSharpDLLPtr(__uuidof(ManagedCSharpClass));

    long lResult = 0;

    // Call the Add method.
    CSharpDLLPtr->Add(5, 10, &lResult);
    long aa;
    aa = 3;
    CPPcallback cppcallback;


    CSharpDLLPtr->CalltheCallbackFun(&cppcallback, &aa);
    wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", lResult);


    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The C++ calls C# function works. But the line 
     CSharpDLLPtr->CalltheCallbackFun(&cppcallback, &aa);

would go into the function QueryInterface,  GetTypeInfo then back to C++ main function directly. That is The line in C#

```
  Console.Write("before call callbackFun\n");
```

Would not be reached.

How should I do to register a C++ callback function in C#?

Answer (score 3):

I don't like `COM` approach (too many code and registrations) and I would recommend you to use the `PInvoke` and `Managed CLI` instead.

But in your case (assuming you already have built big `COM` infrastructure) I can advise to use little `PInvoke` specific workaround.
The Idea is to pass `pointer` to your `CallBack` function as `IntPtr` (`void*` C++ equivalent). And then on C# side convert it back to `Delegate` with

> [Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer(v=vs.110).aspx)

`COM` will not spoil `IntPtr`. I've checked how `IntPtr` converted to `COM` interface. It turns out that on `x64` it becomes `LongLong` and for `x86` it is `Long`. So that type is Ideal to hold pointers (BTW you can pass pointer to your class inside `Callback`). That means that `AnyCPU` configuration will be useless.

Here is code example C# rewriten part:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpLibraryNameSpace
{    
    // Any delegate decorated as for PInoke
    public delegate int NativeDelegateType([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string strMsg);

    // Interface declaration.
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ManagedInterface
    {
        int Add(int Number1, int Number2);

        int CalltheCallbackFun(IntPtr callbackFnPtr);
    };


    // Interface implementation.
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ManagedCSharpClass : ManagedInterface
    {
        public int Add(int Number1, int Number2)
        {
            Console.Write("Inside MANAGED Add Num1={0} Num2={1}\n", Number1, Number2);
            return Number1 + Number2;
        }

        public int CalltheCallbackFun(IntPtr callbackFnPtr)
        {
            Console.Write("Inside MANAGED CalltheCallbackFun Before Call ptr={0}\n", callbackFnPtr);

            //Convert IntPtr to Delegate
            NativeDelegateType callback =
                Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(callbackFnPtr,
                    typeof(NativeDelegateType)) as NativeDelegateType;

            int nRet = callback("Message from C# :)");

            Console.Write("Inside MANAGED CalltheCallbackFun After Call Result={0}\n", nRet);

            return nRet;
        }
    }
}
```

And `C++` client part:

```
#import "CSharpLibrary.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace CSharpLibrary;

int SimpleCallbackFunction(const wchar_t* pszMsg)
{
    wprintf(L"Inside C++ UNMANAGED Callback Param=\"%s\"\n", pszMsg);
    return 77;
}

int main()
{
    wprintf(L"Inside C++ UNMANAGED Start\n");

    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    ManagedInterfacePtr CSharpDLLPtr(__uuidof(ManagedCSharpClass));

    long lResult = 0;

    // Call the Add method.
    CSharpDLLPtr->Add(5, 10, &lResult); //lResult == 15

    //! For x64 you need to convert to LongLong
    CSharpDLLPtr->CalltheCallbackFun((long)SimpleCallbackFunction, &lResult);
    wprintf(L"Inside C++ UNMANAGED Main result is %d\n", lResult);

    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Inside C++ UNMANAGED Start
Inside MANAGED Add Num1=5 Num2=10
Inside MANAGED CalltheCallbackFun Before Call ptr=2625906
Inside C++ UNMANAGED Callback Param="Message from C# :)"
Inside MANAGED CalltheCallbackFun After Call Result=77
Inside C++ UNMANAGED Main result is 77
```

Comment: Thank you, but I should comment here:

it is more good to replace the  type: 

        var 
as

        NativeDelegateType 

for better compatibility

Comment: @GaigerChen I didn't understand about replacing `var` type? Regarding topic I want to add that using `PInvoke` has a lot of advantages: you don't have to write wrappers, you can pass `C++ Arrays`, `LPCTSTR` and `Structs` without explicit conversion, it faster etc...

Comment: At my Environment : VS2005, using of var could not be passed by the compiler, but  NativeDelegateType  could.

Answer (score 1):

Although I still recommend to use `PInvoke` and `Managed CLI` or at least approach from my previous `answer` I want to add `COM` approach answer.

Using `COM wrappers` for `delegates` is not good idea. The following code declares `Callback` as `Interface` from `C#` and takes object which implements this `interface`.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpLibraryNameSpace
{   
    //Callback Interface declaration
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface CallbackInterface1
    {
        int InvokeUnmanaged(string strMsg);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ManagedInterface
    {
        int Add(int Number1, int Number2);
        int CalltheCallbackFun(CallbackInterface1 callback);
    };


    // Interface implementation.
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ManagedCSharpClass : ManagedInterface
    {
        public int Add(int Number1, int Number2)
        {
            Console.Write("Inside MANAGED Add Num1={0} Num2={1}\n", Number1, Number2);
            return Number1 + Number2;
        }

        public int CalltheCallbackFun(CallbackInterface1 callback)
        {
            Console.Write("Inside MANAGED CalltheCallbackFun Before Call\n");

            int nRet = callback.InvokeUnmanaged("Message from C# :)");

            Console.Write("Inside MANAGED CalltheCallbackFun After Call Result={0}\n", nRet);

            return nRet;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to use this `callback` from `C++` you need to make special object. Here is the whole program code:

```
#import "CSharpLibrary.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace CSharpLibrary;

class CPPcallback :public CallbackInterface1
{
public:
    CPPcallback(){};
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount( 
        /* [out] */ UINT *pctinfo)
    {
        *pctinfo = 1;
        return S_OK;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfo( 
        /* [in] */ UINT iTInfo,
        /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
        /* [out] */ ITypeInfo **ppTInfo)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNames( 
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [size_is][in] */ LPOLESTR *rgszNames,
        /* [in] */ UINT cNames,
        /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
        /* [size_is][out] */ DISPID *rgDispId)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke( 
        /* [in] */ DISPID dispIdMember,
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
        /* [in] */ WORD wFlags,
        /* [out][in] */ DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,
        /* [out] */ VARIANT *pVarResult,
        /* [out] */ EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo,
        /* [out] */ UINT *puArgErr)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(/* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [iid_is][out] */ void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject)
    {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown) 
        {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this); 
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }

        if (riid == IID_IDispatch) {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IDispatch*>(this); 
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }

        if (riid == __uuidof(CallbackInterface1)) 
        {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<CallbackInterface1*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }

        *ppvObject = NULL;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef( void)
    {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&_refCount);
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release( void)
    {
        return  InterlockedDecrement(&_refCount);
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall InvokeUnmanaged (
        /*[in]*/ BSTR strMsg,
        /*[out,retval]*/ long * pRetVal ) override
    {
        wprintf(L"Inside C++ UNMANAGED Callback Param=\"%s\"\n", strMsg);
        *pRetVal = 77;
        return S_OK;
    }

private:
    long _refCount;
};

int main()
{
    wprintf(L"Inside C++ UNMANAGED Start\n");

    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    ManagedInterfacePtr CSharpDLLPtr(__uuidof(ManagedCSharpClass));

    long nRes = 0;

    // Call the Add method.
    CSharpDLLPtr->Add(5, 10, &nRes);

    //Callback holder instance
    CPPcallback cppcallback;

    //Call COM Managed method which calls our Callback
    CSharpDLLPtr->CalltheCallbackFun(&cppcallback, &nRes);
    wprintf(L"Inside C++ UNMANAGED Main result is %d\n", nRes);

    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is:

```
Inside C++ UNMANAGED Start
Inside MANAGED Add Num1=5 Num2=10
Inside MANAGED CalltheCallbackFun Before Call
Inside C++ UNMANAGED Callback Param="Message from C# :)"
Inside MANAGED CalltheCallbackFun After Call Result=77
Inside C++ UNMANAGED Main result is 77
```

If you would hide `IDispatch` implementation behind the scene code will be almost as short as code from previous answer BUT you will face all that `COM` specific objects (like `BSTR`, `SAFEARRAY`) it definetly works slowly than `PInvoke`.